# Failed to convert from type [java.lang.Object[]] to type [qbr.entity.nameEntity]

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, rest

I am not asking the question that is already asked here
[Failed to convert from type [java.lang.Object[]] to type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42446506/failed-to-convert-from-type-java-lang-object-to-type)

My entity look like this :

```
    @Entity
public class DuplicateManagerMetricsRelTagEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "sn")
    String sn;

    @Column(name = "clientid")
    String clientid;

    @Column(name = "ticket_count")
    String ticket_count;

    public DuplicateManagerMetricsRelTagEntity(String sn, String clientid, String ticket_count) {
        this.sn = sn;
        this.clientid = clientid;
        this.ticket_count = ticket_count;
    }

    public DuplicateManagerMetricsRelTagEntity() {

    }
```

My controller look like this :

```
@RequestMapping("/qbr/duplicatemanager/{clientid}/{appid}/{releasetag}/")
@CrossOrigin
public List<DuplicateManagerMetricsRelTagEntity> getAllDuplicateManagerFromReleaseTag(@PathVariable String clientid, @PathVariable String[] appid, @PathVariable String releasetag) {
    logger.info("Returing all duplicate managers of client {} appId {} from release tag {} ", clientid, appid, releasetag);

    System.out.println("data in controller : " + clientid + " " + appid + " " + releasetag);
    return duplicateManagerMetricsService.getAllDuplicateManagerFromReleaseTag(clientid, appid, releasetag);

}
```

My service look like this :

```
public List<DuplicateManagerMetricsRelTagEntity> getAllDuplicateManagerFromReleaseTag(String clientid, String[] appid, String releasetag) {
    try {
        System.out.println("data in service : "+ clientid + " " + appid + " " + releasetag);
        return duplicateManagerMetricsRepository.getAllDuplicateManagerfromReleaseTag(clientid, appid, releasetag);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e);
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

My Repository look like this :

```
@Query(value = "select a.sn, a.clientid, a.ticket_count from dbtable as a where a.clientid = ?1 AND a.appid in (?2)  AND a.releasetag=?3", nativeQuery = true)
List<DuplicateManagerMetricsRelTagEntity> getAllDuplicateManagerfromReleaseTag(String clientid, String[] appid, String releasetag);
```

since i am not getting appid data, i was supposed to get[657-001] but it is printing its object and the error i am getting is :

```
DuplicateManagerMetricsController - Returing all duplicate managers of client 657 appId [657-001] from release tag WIL657.2021.05-001 
data in controller : 657 [Ljava.lang.String;@63108943 WIL657.2021.05-001
data in service : 657 [Ljava.lang.String;@63108943 WIL657.2021.05-001
2022-09-02 05:08:54 DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - select a.sn, a.clientid, a.ticket_count from dbtable as a where a.clientid = ? AND a.appid in (?)  AND a.releasetag=?
2022-09-02 05:08:54 WARN  o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 933, SQLState: 42000
2022-09-02 05:08:54 ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
 
[ERROR] 2022-09-02 05:08:54.566 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DuplicateManagerMetricsService - org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are extracting fields (a.sn, a.clientid, a.ticket_count) which is not a DuplicateManagerMetricsRelTagEntity type. So since you have not asked hibernate to extract the complete object but a few fields(does not matter if your fields are exactly same as the fields in the object) - so hibernate extracts it as Object[] and then is trying to map to DuplicateManagerMetricsRelTagEntity and hence the issue.

You can use: [JPA Projection/DTO](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-projection-query-to-a-dto-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)

In your case you can use JPQL and :

```
"select a from DuplicateManagerMetricsRelTagEntity a where a.clientid = ?1 AND a.appid in (?2)  AND a.releasetag=?3"
```

Or for native queries you an try:

```
select * from table_name where conditions;
```

**NOTE:** It has been long since I used hibernate or jpa. So the queries might be not completely accurate. Please do check up on the proper syntax. Main idea is to let you know how hibernate understands and tries to map the type. Since you have a,b,c -> Object[] is extracted and cannot be mapped to your entity.